# Wordpress child taxonomy on click to link to the child archive and side bar category to expand/active

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Below is my html

```
<div class="tp-toggle-holder">
    <div class="tp-toggle-row">
        <!--<h3 class="active">Fresh, Frozen &amp; Chilled</h3>-->
        <h3 class="1">Fresh, Frozen &amp; Chilled</h3>
        <div class="tp-toggle-details active-toggle">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/coupons/fresh-frozen-chilled/fruits/">Fruits</a></li>
                <li><a href="/coupons/fresh-frozen-chilled/vegetables/">Vegetables</a></li>
                <li><a href="/coupons/fresh-frozen-chilled/chicken/">Chicken</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tp-toggle-row">
        <!--<h3 class="">Dairy, Chilled &amp; Eggs</h3>-->
        <h3 class="">Dairy, Chilled &amp; Eggs</h3>
        <div class="tp-toggle-details ">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/coupons/dairy-chilled-eggs/eggs/">Eggs</a></li>
                <li><a href="/coupons/dairy-chilled-eggs/bread/">Bread</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tp-toggle-row">
        <!--<h3 class="">Drinks</h3>-->
        <h3 class="">Drinks</h3>
        <div class="tp-toggle-details ">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/coupons/drinks/hot-beverages/">Hot Beverages</a></li>
                <li><a href="/coupons/drinks/juices/">Juices</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when first page load, first ul will be active. When user click on li links in eg. Dairy, Chilled & Eggs it will load to /coupons/dairy-chilled-eggs/eggs/ archive and Dairy, Chilled & Eggs sidebar will be active. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `wp_list_categories()` with your taxonomy instead then it supplies a current class to the LI that you can target with either CSS or JS.

Something similar to this...

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'coupons', // im assuming your taxonomy slug is coupons
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'title_li' => '',
);
?>

<ul>
    <?php wp_list_categories($args);?>
</ul>
```

[wp_list_categories() documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/)

Comment: Thanks and yes my taxonomy is coupons
`code
<h3 class="<?php echo ($counter==0) ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h3>
`

Comment: `code
wpjQuery(".tp-toggle-row ul li a").click(function() {
   if(wpjQuery('.tp-toggle-row h3').hasClass('active')) {
  } else {
   wpjQuery( ".tp-toggle-row h3" ).each(function() {
    if(wpjQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
     wpjQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
     wpjQuery(this).next('.tp-toggle-details').slideToggle('hide');
    }
   });
  }
  wpjQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
  wpjQuery(this).next('.tp-toggle-details').slideToggle('slow');
  e.preventDefault();
  });
`

Comment: Pardon my above format, it is use to expand other parent taxonomy on click. my question is how do i make it expand such that when i click on the child taxonomy it will direct me to the child taxonomy page and the selected child's parent taxonomy maintain expanded. Please advise.

Comment: I tried using below code
`code
var path = window.location.href;
     wpjQuery('.tp-toggle-row ul li a').each(function() {
      if (this.href === path) {
    wpjQuery(".tp-toggle-row ul li a").parent(".tp-toggle-row h3").addClass('active');
       wpjQuery(this).parents(".tp-toggle-row h3").addClass('active');
    wpjQuery(this).parent(".tp-toggle-details").addClass('active-toggle');      
      }
     });
`
if i didn't use parent all of my "toggle-row h3" will become active. But after i add parent it doesn't work. Kindly advise. Thanks